# Selecting entity interactions from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm tasked with generating a report on data in a SQL Server database dealing with entities entering and exiting areas. The report is to identify when a pair of entities are interacting with each other in a single area, report the duration they interacted, and also the start and end times of the interaction.

The schema for the `AreaEvents` table looks something like this:

```
EventId uniqueidentifier,
EntityId uniqueidentifier,
AreaId uniqueidentifier,
EnterTime datetime,
ExitTime datetime
```

This is the `SELECT` statement I've came up with, but the performance is a bit lacking. I had to add a `DISTINCT` clause, paired with the `CASE WHEN a.EntityId < b.EntityId` for selecting EntityIds to prevent reverse duplicated rows from appearing in resulting dataset.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.AreaId, 
    -- Select the latest enter time from the entity interaction
    CASE
        WHEN a.EnterTime >= b.EnterTime THEN a.EnterTime
        ELSE b.EnterTime
    END as StartTime,

    -- Select the earliest exit time from the entity interaction
    CASE
        WHEN a.ExitTime <= b.ExitTime THEN a.ExitTime
        ELSE b.ExitTime
    END as EndTime,

    -- Diff the start time and end time to get the duration
    DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,   
        CASE
            WHEN a.EnterTime >= b.EnterTime THEN a.EnterTime
            ELSE b.EnterTime
        END,    
        CASE
            WHEN a.ExitTime <= b.ExitTime THEN a.ExitTime
            ELSE b.ExitTime
        END) as Duration,

    -- So we can distinctly select the rows, we need to make sure the 
    -- same entities are always selected for entity 1 and entity 2 for
    -- the same interactions.
    CASE WHEN a.EntityId < b.EntityId 
        THEN a.EntityId 
        ELSE b.EntityId 
    END as EntityId1,

    -- So we can distinctly select the rows, we need to make sure the 
    -- same entities are always selected for entity 1 and entity 2 for
    -- the same interactions.
    CASE WHEN a.EntityId < b.EntityId 
        THEN b.EntityId 
        ELSE a.EntityId 
    END as EntityId2
FROM AreaEvents a
JOIN AreaEvents b
ON
    a.EntityId != b.EntityId AND
    a.AreaId = b.AreaId AND
    a.EnterTime <= b.ExitTime AND 
    a.ExitTime >= b.EnterTime
```

Are the `CASE WHEN`s bloating the performance here, or is attributed to the `FROM` and `WHERE` clause here? SQL is not my strongest suit here; is there an alternative approach that would be better?

Comment: Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax - easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've updated the select statement to use a `JOIN`. Was this intended to increase the performance? It seemed to have comparable results to the `WHERE` clause.